# Take Ryanair out of the vent

Tags: riddle

> My children
>   A problem
>   With a drink I can clean
>   Not left to investors
>   Is at Wimbledon seen?

Question: What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A fitting word for this is an

> issue.

My children

> Issue meaning offspring or progeny.

A problem

> A concern or complication.

With a drink I can clean

> **t**(ea) + issue giving tissue, which can clean.

Not left to investors

> A rights (not left) issue is an invitation to investors to buy additional new shares in the company.

Is at Wimbledon seen?

> Is Sue (Barker) - the former tennis player who presents Wimbledon for the BBC.

Title: Take Ryanair out of the vent

> Ryanair's [airline code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_codes_(R)) is FR. Subtracting these letters from fissure (the vent) gives issue.

Comment: You've got the right overall answer and correctly explained most of the clues, but the word 'left' is important in the fourth line and I was originally planning to use the word 'crevice' instead of 'vent' for the title. It would only have worked with Ryanair, not any other airline.

Comment: @GordonK Ah, good Ryanair clue - I will update. (And retry the not left).

Comment: Spot on! Well Done.

Comment: maybe rot13(vairfgbef vf orsber vffhr va n qvpgvbanel, naq vs yvfgrq nycunorgvpnyyl vairfgbef vf ba gur evtug bs vffhr)?